# Java API to create elasticsearch index, kibana unable to query

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana-4

I use elasticsearch Java API already created logstash - 2015.07.30 index, but in kibana unable to query to the index, excuse me somebody in the same problem?

Comment: I think spaces in the name on your index is not allowed